# Loop object which has property value of n in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, prototype

This is the `member` object:

```
function member() {
       this.name = name;
       this.isTaken = false;
    }
```

This is the array object:

```
function group() {
   this.members = [new member(blahhh)];
}
```

Now, I want to create a prototype of the group object that will iterate and generate a random number based on the index which has a value of true in `isTaken` property inside the array. If one object has been chosen, its `isTaken` property will be change to true.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do. Can you try to clarify?

Comment: I want to get a random index from the members array which isTaken propterty is false, which in this case is the default. Then the isTaken property of the index selected will be change to true. Then the iteration will repeat until all the isTaken property of the object is true.

Comment: Side note: Overwhelmingly, the convention in JavaScript is that constructor functions are initially capitalized, e.g. `Member` and `Group`. It's useful to follow conventions like that when asking for help, as it helps people understand your code more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you want to write a function that will set `isTaken` to `true` on one of the `member` objects in `this.members`, with the object chosen at random. If so:

```
group.prototype.setTakenAtRandom = function() {
    var member = this.members[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.members.length)];
    member.isTaken = true;
};
```

That makes no attempt to avoid members that *already* have `isTaken` set to `true`. If you want to do that, one way is to first filter out previously-taken ones:

```
group.prototype.setTakenAtRandom = function() {
    var available = this.members.filter(function(m) { return !m.isTaken; });
    if (available.length) {
        var member = available[Math.floor(Math.random() * available.length)];
        member.isTaken = true;
    }
};
```

`Math.floor(Math.random() * x)` will give you a value that's `0 <= n < x` (that is, it might be `0`, but it won't be `x`), so that's how we can randomly pick an entry from the array.

---

From your comment on the question:

> Then the iteration will repeat until all the isTaken property of the object is true.

Okay, then we want to have `setTakenAtRandom` tell us if it ran out of members:

```
group.prototype.setTakenAtRandom = function() {
    var available = this.members.filter(function(m) { return !m.isTaken; });
    if (available.length) {
        var member = available[Math.floor(Math.random() * available.length)];
        member.isTaken = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
};
```

Then, just call `setTakenAtRandom` repeatedly until it returns `false`.